# How to fix dependency injection when upgrading play framework from 2.5.x to 2.6.x Scala

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework-2.0

I am trying to upgrade from play 2.5.x to 2.6.3. (Because 2.5.x doesn't support multipart post in WS. import play.api.libs.ws.DefaultBodyWritables._ throws Exceptions. The code example in the official document doesn't work. The compiler needs the Body Writables which is not provided until 2.6.x)

So I changed the plugin.sbt version to 2.6.3 and upgraded sbt to 0.13.15. And edit the build.sbt file to add guice and json. The project compiles fine. But when I started with sbt run, and visit http://localhost:9000, it throws a bunch of Exception related to a jar file I have in the local lib/ directory. The same code worked just fine with 2.5.x.

Here's the exception:

> 1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/util/concurrent/FutureFallback
>     at db.ConcreteGGDB.(ConcreteGGDB.scala:24)
>     at Module.configure(Module.scala:29) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> Module)
>     while locating db.ConcreteGGDB

Any idea if this is related to the local jar is not compatible with 2.6.x? or I need to change some code to do dependency injection other than specify in the Module.scala file? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

[Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/twitter/finagle/http/Method$Get$](https://github.com/twitter/finagle/issues/634)

> NoClassDefFound means that there's a class that your code needs, but
>   it can't find it. This typically happens when your project
>   transitively depends on more than one version of a library. For
>   example, imagine that you're building project A, which depends on lib
>   X, and project B, which also depends on lib X. However, project B was
>   built against an older version of lib X, which used to have a class,
>   but which it no longer exports.
>
> A => B => X (version 1)
>
> A => X (version 2)
>
> Then when it runs, A makes a call into B, which tries to make a call
>   into X, but because the project now uses the newer version instead of
>   the older version, it can't find the class it needs.
>
> I would encourage you to use sbt-dependency-graph to see which
>   versions of [library name] you're depending on transitively, and ensure that
>   every library you use uses the same version of [library name].

Looks like an issue with the local jar.